# CTE Query to CONCAT text (over 10,000 rows)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, cte, recursive, query-performance

I am trying to construct a CTE query to loop through rows of data and concatenate text into one line for each **SampleUserNumber**.

Below is what I am working with:

```
CREATE TABLE #SampleTable
(
SampleRowID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
SampleUserNumber INT,
SampleLineNumber INT,
SampleTextLine VARCHAR(1000)
)
```

[image: Sample Data]

Here is my CTE Query:

[image: CTE Query]

Here is the Output:

[image: Result]

The CTE Query works and the result is correct, but my main issue is the performance and the amount of records I have to process. Right now I am dealing with 100,000 records at a bare minimum.

Questions:

1. Have I written the query incorrectly to handle 100,000 records? Is there a more efficient way to write the CTE?
2. Is there another way more efficient and better way to do this? [looping would be out of the question unless I have no other choice]

Sorry for all the images. I figured it would be much easier to show everything rather than write it out here.

Thank you.

Comment: You are better off to use [for xml path or clr](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation) to see perf gain. CTE does in any way speed up perf. See this as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639262/optimal-way-to-concatenate-aggregate-strings

Comment: Also please just put the query text in your question. We are more than happy to help you with formatting, but nobody is going to transcribe your query from a screen shot in order to compare performance or validate correct results. And don't discount loops (or really, anything) out of hand. *Generally* they are poor performers, but there are some cases where they are the best option. "It depends" applies to almost everything in SQL Server.

Comment: @Kin I will check this out thank you! I did not see your reply or the user below you. I was scrolled down to the bottom.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I did try a loop but I found that it was taking way to long, but I do agree with your statement "it depends". I was just looking for alternatives and better options. That is the only reason I did not paste the code directly due to formatting and I did not want to burden anyone with the formatting aspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does this approach do in comparison?

```
SELECT 
  SampleUserNumber, 
  CombinedMessage = STUFF(
    (SELECT N' ' + SampleTextLine FROM #SampleTable
       WHERE SampleUserNumber = t.SampleUserNumber
       ORDER BY SampleLineNumber
       FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value(N'.[1]',N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')
FROM #SampleTable AS t
GROUP BY SampleUserNumber
ORDER BY SampleUserNumber;
```

It would probably be useful for your #temp table to have a clustered index on `SampleUserNumber, SampleLineNumber` or at least a non-clustered on those two columns that `INCLUDE`s `SampleTextLine`.

In SQL Server 2017 you would be able to use a much more straightforward approach, almost guaranteed to be faster:

```
SELECT SampleUserNumber, 
  CombinedMessage = STRING_AGG(CONVERT(varchar(max),SampleTextLine), ' ') 
                    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SampleLineNumber)
FROM #SampleTable
GROUP BY SampleUserNumber 
ORDER BY SampleUserNumber;
```

To avoid the `CONVERT` you could just make your #temp table column a `MAX` type.

Comment: The XML approach worked like a charm! Thank you! I have not tried the clustered index approach just yet, but I will see what happens in terms of performance. Lastly, unfortunately I am not using 2017 or have access to it but I did read up on the STRING_AGG function. Thank you yet again!